# How can I destroy the buttons generated using a for loop (after been clicked...)

Tags: python, tkinter

I already generated the buttons which their name is based on the list **output1**.

So, This program will create 4 buttons respectively from 'key1' to 'key4'
, whenever I click the button **key1**, the search box B will be replaced by "key1"
,similarly, button key 2,key3,key4 will replace "key2","key3","key4" respectively in search box B...

My objective is once I click one of these buttons, It will insert the word in the seach box B, and **these 4 buttons will automatically be deleted**

```
root = Tk()

def setTextInput(text):
    B.delete(0,"end")
    B.insert(0, text)
    for k in Autput1:
        Autput1[k].destroy()    

j=0

if j==0:

    output1 = ['key1','key2','key3','key4']
    
    global Autput1
    Autput1 = []
    
    k=0
    
    for e in output1:                                                                                             
        Autput1.append(Button(root,text=e,command=lambda e=e:setTextInput(str(e))))
        Autput1[k].grid()
        print(Autput1)
        k+=1

A = Label(root,text="Search your song here",font=('Roboto',10),bg='#c4302b')
A.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)

B = Entry(root,font=('Roboto',20))
B.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)

C= Button(root,image=img,command=getsong)
C.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the part of how I try to destroy the button which appends inside the list Autput1.

```
  for k in Autput1:
    Autput1[k].destroy()
```

and This is the error and the only problem I try to fix

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button
```

You might be wondering what is the value Autput1

```
   [<tkinter.Button object .!button2>, <tkinter.Button object .!button3>, <tkinter.Button object 
   .!button4>, <tkinter.Button object .!button5>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are iterating over `Autput`, so `k` is each button and don't index:

```
for k in Autput1:
    k.destroy()
```

If you are using `range(len())` then it will work, because then you will be iterating using index:

```
for k in range(len(Autput1)):
    Autput1[k].destroy()
```